# Rails Nested Route For Singular Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a nested route on a singular resource

```
map.resource :account, :controller => "users" do |page|
  page.resources :feeds
end
```

I'm trying to make a form to add a feed.  I start with this...

```
<% form_for @feed do |f| %>
undefined method `feeds_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x2123174>
```

So I try

```
<% form_for [current_user,@feed] do |f| %>
undefined method `user_feeds_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x20b3e00>
```

I guess that is due to renaming it from "users" to "account"?  So I tried

```
<% form_for account_feeds_path(@feed) do |f| %>
`@/account/feeds.%23%3Cfeed:0x22ea5c0%3E' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

Not sure what that error means.  So I've resorted to using doing this which works:

```
<% form_for @feed, :url=>{:action=>:create} do |f| %>
```

Is that really the best way?  In other words, is there no way to use named routes in this situation?

Comment: Try running `rake routes` and see shows up for feeds.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to do is

```
<% form_for [:account, @feed] do |f| %>
```

form_for will then look to use the account_feeds_path with POST when @feed is a new record and account_feed_path(@feed) with PUT when @feed is not a new record.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused here about nested (+named) routes and singular resources. I'm guessing that what you're trying to do is have a singular `feed` resource that belongs to a user (account), right?

If so, your existing routes

```
map.resource :account, :controller => "users" do |page|
  page.resources :feeds
end
```

should perhaps be

```
map.resources :accounts, :controller => "users" do |account|
  account.resource :feed
end
```

Note that `accounts` are plural resources, but the feed is singular. That gives you the usual RESTful routes on your accounts (i.e. your users)... but a singular 'feed' resource. You won't need to refer to the id of your feed - but usually just work from the @account.feed

use `rake routes` to show you the full list of routes that this creates.

`account_feed_path(@account)`, for instance will give you the Show page for a feed.

The paths therefore give you the ability to use form helpers like so:

```
<% form_for :feed, account_feed_path(@account) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Actually I'm trying to do the opposite.  Every user has one account, but can have multiple feeds.  So the account is singular, the feeds plural (or whatever it's called).  You're right in clarifying that my route is named too tho.  If you have any ideas based on this new info I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: So do you have a User model AND an Account model? or are they the same thing?

Comment: Only a user model.  I copied the route from an AuthLogic tutorial...I think the reasoning behind it is that when a user is logged in, they are treating it like a singular resource...they just have one "account" (which is really just editing their own user model).  Whereas an admin might use regular "users" routes since they can see lists of all users, etc.  Anyway, I'm not married to the idea if there is a good reason not too...just figured there should be some easier way to use routes, even in this situation.  Thanks again!

Comment: In the case of user vs. admin updating of User models, I would recommend creating a separate controller for admins with namespacing. That way, you can have a standard UsersController that edits a singular User model, and an Admin::UsersController that edits a collection of Users.