# Rails finds no route in a on-to-one relation (using Devise)

Tags: activerecord, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm facing a problem with a nested route in Rails an I can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong.

In a nutshell: I use Devise for authentication an registration. Now I want to have the user enter more detailed information about his contact data. To keep the user model small, I want to use a different model called account. As a user only will have one account, I use a on-to-one association and a nested route. But somehow the routing does not work.
This is my user model:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

and this is my account model:

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :anrede, :land, :nachname, :plz, :stadt, :strasse, :user_id, :vorname
 belongs_to :user
end
```

and my route file looks like this:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'members'
 resources :users do
  resource :account
 end
```

As a user might not have a account yet, I test this in my view:

```
        <% if current_user.account.try %>
        <li><%= link_to "Account", user_account_path %></li>
        <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "create Account", new_user_account_path %></li>
        <% end %>
```

but when I enter the root path with a signed in user, Rails tells me

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts"}
```

but there is a new action in my accounts_controller.rb as I have scaffolded the whole CRUD set (edited create with current_user.build_account) and it's also the path given by rake routes.

I'm desperately stuck in this! Could anybody help me, please?

**EDIT**
This is the output of my rake routes:

```
        user_account POST   /users/:user_id/account(.:format)      accounts#create
    new_user_account GET    /users/:user_id/account/new(.:format)  accounts#new
   edit_user_account GET    /users/:user_id/account/edit(.:format) accounts#edit
                     GET    /users/:user_id/account(.:format)      accounts#show
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/account(.:format)      accounts#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/account(.:format)      accounts#destroy
```

**EDIT2**

this is the error message for the action new form:

```
NoMethodError in Accounts#new

Showing /home/stonjarks/Work/toytrade_devise/app/views/accounts/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `accounts_path' for #<#<Class:0xa44d0cc>:0xab6222c>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @account.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@account.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this account from being saved:</h2>
```

I solved this using this SO hack, but it's a strange behavior anyway:

[Rails Nested Route For Singular Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157574/rails-nested-route-for-singular-resource)

```
<%= form_for @account,:url=>{:action=>:create}
```

But I still don't get the point of this routing anyway. Despite this, I can't manage to find a route to show the account:

/users/1/account

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountsController#show

Couldn't find Account without an ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_user_account_path` is missing a user instance which should be provided for example:

`new_user_account_path(current_user)`

If you look at the following line:

```
new_user_account GET    /users/:user_id/account/new(.:format)  accounts#new
```

You can see that the path demands a :user_id - a user instance.

You can read [here](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/rails-dead-end-no-route-matches/) for further clarification of your problem.

Comment: Erez, the routing to the edit form works! But could you tell me, which variable I have to declare in the form because it's now complaining about a missing "accounts_path" in my form template.

Comment: I think you should add `resources :accounts` to your routes.rb (not nested inside the resources :users block)

Comment: I was at this point before. But I suffer a mistake. When I enter 'account_path' in my view, I receive a 

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts"} 

error.
When I enter 'account_path(current_user)' I will be routed to 
/accounts/1, which is the current_user's id but not the account.id

and when I enter 'account_path(@account)' I receive 
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts", :id=>nil}

It feels that nesting is the _right way_ but it just won't work.

Comment: account_path should receive an Account instance

Comment: Yes that's right. But wouldn't that be 'account_path(@account)'? 

But this generates a No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts", :id=>nil} Error.

So this means, that it doesn't pass the instance variable. Confusing... 

But I really have to thank you, @erez. I think that I#m on the right path. Will mark your answer as correct, as the the hint for the instance was right. But I hope to solve my current problem.

Comment: `account_path(@account)` will only work if @account has already been saved to the DB and has an ID. If `@account = Account.new` and was not saved to the DB then you should use `new_account_path`